# How to retrieve the audiences for a given campaign via the Google Ads API

Tags: python, google-ads-api

I'm trying to fetch the audiences (Custom intent, Custom affinity) of all my enabled google display campaigns.

I thought I can get it through the `CampaignCriterionService`, but the returned data is empty.

```py
    campaign_criterion_service = ADWORDS_CLIENT.GetService(
        'CampaignCriterionService', version='v201809')

    selector = {
        'fields': ['CampaignId', 'Id', 'CriteriaType', "PlacementUrl",
                   'KeywordText', "ChannelName", "AppId", "DisplayName", "CampaignStatus", "CampaignName"],
        'predicates': [{
            'field': 'CriteriaType',
            'operator': 'IN',
            'values': [
                'CUSTOM_AFFINITY',
                'CUSTOM_INTENT'
            ]
        },
        {
            'field': 'CampaignStatus',
            'operator': 'IN',
            'values': [
                'ENABLED'
            ]
        }


        ],
        'paging': {
            'startIndex': 0,
            'numberResults': 500
        }
    }

    page = campaign_criterion_service.get(selector)
```

Any clues?

Comment: Is the `CampaignCriterionService ` the right direction?

Comment: @Stewart_R Any idea?

Comment: This question shows no attempt on your part and should be closed or improved.

Comment: @MadPhysicist what do you mean by that?

Comment: I'm literally lost, not even sure how to search for this. Google results aren't really helping here. I was able to retrieve the "LANGUAGE" and "KEYWORDS" of my targeting, but nothing about the audiences.

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for ways to to report your results, read about [reporting with google adwords](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/reporting#create_a_report_definition). The recommended way of using this with the python lib is described [Here](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/samples/python/reporting).